# Can a word be monosyllabic and polymorphemic?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is it possible? If yes are there any examples? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3):

Consider *cats*, formed from the morpheme *cat* and the morpheme *-s*.

*cats* = *cat* + *-s*

*Cats* is monosyllabic and polymorphemic.

---

Consider also *scratched*, formed from the morpheme *scratch* and the morpheme *-ed*.

*scratched* = *scratch* + *-ed*.

By many accounts, *scratched* is monosyllabic.

Comment: Agreed. But non-syllabic affixes are likely the only case where there are two morphemes in a monosyllabic word. There can, of course, be two [phonesthemes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf) in a monosyllable, like _stump_, where the assonance _st-_ refers to `1-dimensional extended`and the rime [_-ump_](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf) refers to `3-dimensional`, creating a monosyllable that means 'a 3-dimensional object that used to be a 1-dimensional extended object'. However, these are not morphemes.

Comment: @JohnLawler, meaningful assonance and rimes interest me to no end. Is there a good primer or survey piece on phonosemantics (preferably not overly technical) that you would recommend? Maybe you've written something yourself.

Comment: [The link I gave above](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf) is a paper I wrote, and [here is a bibliography with links](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/monobib.pdf).